# How to clone entity object in another entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I would need to clone an entity object to another entity.

Actually im using this code to clone:

```
$a = $em->find(Entity::class,1);

$b = clone $a;
$em->persist($b);
$em->flush();
```

Everything is fine , but i need to clone that object in another entity like:

```
$a = $em->find(Entity::class,1);

$b = clone $a; <----- in EntityBackup::class
$em->persist($b);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Are you asking how to get the entity manager from inside of an entity?

Answer (score 1):

You could hydrate you EntityBackup using a Serializer/Deserializer because the serializer transform your object into desired type of data (array, json, ...) and when you want to deserialize, you could give the destination object class:

```php
    $context = ['json_encode_options' => \JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE];
    $serializer = new Serializer([
        new ProblemNormalizer(),
        new JsonSerializableNormalizer(),
        new ConstraintViolationListNormalizer(),
        new DateTimeNormalizer($context),
        new DateTimeZoneNormalizer(),
        new DateIntervalNormalizer(),
        new DataUriNormalizer(),
        new ArrayDenormalizer(),
        new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, new ReflectionExtractor()),
    ], [
        new JsonEncoder(),
    ]);
    
    $a = $em->find(Entity::class, 1);
    $aSerialized = $serializer->serialize($request, 'json', $context);
    
    $b = $serializer->deserialize($aSerialized, EntityBackup::class, 'json', $context);
    
    $em->persist($b);
    $em->flush();
```

Or use a simple function to iterate over each property:

```php
    $a = $em->find(Entity::class, 1);
    $b = new EntityBackup();
    $reflect = new ReflectionClass($a);
    $props   = $reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC | ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED | ReflectionProperty::IS_PR);
    foreach ($props as $prop) {
        $getMethodName = 'set'.ucfirst($prop->getName());
        $setMethodName = 'set'.ucfirst($prop->getName());
        if (method_exists($b, $setMethodName)) {
            $b->$setMethodName($a->$getMethodName());
        }
    }
    
    $em->persist($b);
    $em->flush();
```

Not really tested but you got the idea! :)

Comment: Thx for the hint,
I was using the second method but i tought that anicer way was possible.
Really like:
Get -> Copy ->Transfer

Comment: You could build your own :p

Comment: As an alternative to using reflection, the entity manager exposes the entity mapping information.  Might be a bit cleaner.  But regardless of how you do it trying to make a deep clone will be interesting.